# Suggestions for rescue of an ATmega328P

Tags: arduino, atmega, avrdude

I have an ATmega328P that seems to be fried. It was in an Arduino board (Freakduino-chibi, specifically) and working when it suddenly stopped responding at all.

Investigation showed that the fault followed the chip from board to board.

Using a BusPirate, I tried to access the chip via avrdude and the ICSP header on the Arduino. No dice: avrdude failed to initialize the chip. Using the same board and a different 328P, avrdude was successful.

Any thoughts on how to possibly resurrect the broken chip?

Comment: have you tried banging it firmly on the side?

Comment: Is it possible to set fuses in the Arduino environment? It doesn't look like the Freakduino-chibi has an external oscillator, which would be a problem if the ext. osc. fuses are set. Just put a 1MHz clock on the XTAL pin.

Comment: Banging it had no effect.  :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you "fried" it by burning your fuses incorrectly, then you just need some high voltage programmer like original STK500 or [similar](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/avrdoper.html). Otherwise buy the new AVR MEGA chip and simply replace the bad one. If you are lucky then nothing else was burnt.

Comment: @Andreja: Are you sure the AVRISP mkII can do HVSP?  The documentation says nothing about it and I don't see any sort of HV source on the one sitting at my desk.

Comment: @Nick T I'll do some more research and look for sources on that. I remember that couple years ago when I was researching AVR devices, I found info about mkII ISP doing high voltage programming, but I didn't savve the link.

Comment: @Nick T It turns out that I confused AVRISP for some other programmer. I apologize for spreading misinformation. I did find couple of other programmers which do support HV like [this](http://www.scienceprog.com/avr-serial-and-parallel-high-voltage-programmer/) or [this](http://mightyohm.com/blog/2008/09/arduino-based-avr-high-voltage-programmer/).

Comment: Interesting. I'll see if I can cobble together something that will do the HV programming and see if I can clear the fuses.

Answer (score 6):

The [HV Rescue Shield 2.x](http://mightyohm.com/blog/2010/12/new-product-hv-rescue-shield-2-0/) is a high voltage parallel mode fuse programmer for Atmel AVR microcontrollers.

[image]

If that doesn't fix it...

[image]

Comment: Well, it was a bit funny once. Don't kill it.

Answer (score 0):

It's either dead or needs fuses resetting as other have said.

If you have access to an electron microscope and some impossibly thin wires or a very precise and glitchy power supply, other options are available:

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sps32/mcu_lock.html